# Facebook key hash does not match any stored key hashes

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sharer

I'm really having troubles with the Facebook hash key.
I generated it in my Eclipse.. proof:
[image]

Then I went to https://developers.facebook.com/ and registered a new app.
[image]
[image]

And finally I've set my hashkey at the settings of Facebook developers:
[image]

But no whatter I do I keep getting the same error log:
"Key hash B5dWUEYfZJL/...........jyA= does not match any stored key hashes"

Does anybody know what I did wrong or how I can fix this problem?
If I used the id and name from the HelloFacebookSample inside my own app everything works.
So it HAS to do with the key hash, id or name I've set somewhere most likely..

Thank you,
Yenthe

Comment: The screen cap where you're showing the key hash settings is the wrong place. "Sample App Settings" is only for key hashes for the sample apps that ship with the SDK (so you can build them locally). You should put the key hashes under the "Android" tab in your app settings.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean and that was my initial fault. I then moved it to the Android tab, but neither that was a succes. I had to manually remove my hash key and generate a new one before it all started working.

Comment: delete your app from developers.facebook.com and try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app/6665263#6665263

Comment: Generate SHA1 inside android studio and convert it to hash from here: http://fbkeyhash.com/index.php

Answer (score 43, accepted):

After hours of trying I've finally found a solution.

1. Delete any app on the website of Facebook (developers.facebook.com)
2. Delete the file debug.keystore under `C:\Users\yourUserName\.android`
3. Generate a new key (by running your app again)
4. Create a new app on developers.facebook.com and add the new hash key
5. Re-run your app
6. Succes!

Comment: Thanks! This really works but what if I have a couple of apps registered on the Developers site of Facebook and this issue comes over and over again from time to time?

Comment: @Yulian I'm not sure, that sounds like a very annoying problem.. I'm not sure about this as I only have one app on the Developers site. Sorry!

Comment: Good to hear that my solution is still working @FernandoP.G.! I'm amazed too that this error is still here after over a year..

Comment: Now what do we do if we already have thousands of users, just recreating the app isn't exactly a great idea.

Comment: My Review got success. If I create a new app then again I want to submit for review. Is creation new app is mandatory?

Comment: Saved my day. Had the same issue. Just changing current FB app with new app solved every thing. Thanks

Comment: I have very similar situation to yours. I didn't remove everything, but created new license, went to my regular FB page - Settings - Apps - Removed the app from the list. Changed hash key in dev account and reinstalled fb app and own app. And now it works...It seems fb "remembers" hash keys.

Comment: Deleting apps is not an option, This solved the problem https://github.com/AntonioCuevaUrraco/nativescript-facebook-login/issues/14

Comment: Regenerating `debug.keystore` can complicate matters as if you are using firebase with Google Sign-In it will no longer work as a new SHA-1 key will be generated and you would have to update it in your firebase app page

Comment: What about apps that are already on the store and that have users already using facebook? You can't just delete the app.

Comment: I have the same error but when I didn't set any password in "Enter keystore password:" (Leave it blank and just hit Enter) then it works. It gives some warning but it works

Comment: I have permissions on the app, it would be a a long process to get things in order again if I remove it

Answer (score 89):

> DATE UPDATED EVERY TIME I GOT UPVOTE AS I KNOW IT IS STILL VALID

DATE: 29/02/2023 **(29th of Feb 2024)**

This is how I solved this problem

1. I have got the SHA1 from [`signingReport`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67866731/9138982)

(found in gradle-->app/Tasks/android/signingReport)

Copy the SHA1 value to your clipboard

like this `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`

2. `Facebook sdk` requires it to be in base64 hash key so we open http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php

to convert your SHA1 value to base64.

This is what Facebook requires
get the generated hash " ********************= "

3. open `https://developers.facebook.com/`
4. select your project
   in the setting tab, basic/Key Hashes add the generated key.
5. don't forget to save changes.

Comment: Can't see `app/Tasks/android/signingReport` anywhere in my project folders

Comment: @AntonDuzenko on the right section you will see gradle tab open it then go to app/tasks/android/signingReport or see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68587380/9138982

Comment: That one worked for me.
Conversion of the sha1 to base64 is the best technique, awesome.

Comment: @Ammar, pleased that I could help you

Comment: haha, i remember I used this trick back in 2019 and it's still valid.

Answer (score 86):

If your login is working without installing facebook app and not working when facebook app is installed due to error "hash key has not match" then do following steps

1 ) Launch your app and try to log in with facebook. A dialog will open and tell you: "the key has not been found in the facebook developer console and also show the hash key.

2 ) Note down that hash key.

3 ) Put it into your facebook developer console where you first generated your api key and remove the hash key with new and save. Now you are done. Anyone that downloads your app, published with earlier used keystore can log into facebook.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Nope, didn't work for me. It still works fine without facebook app but if fb app is installed it gives me same error

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: Release key hash doesn't work for me, but Debug key hash worked ok

Comment: Can you please tell me about the concept of keyhashes, what is it actually and on what criteria these gets generated ?

Comment: should I remove all previous Hash Keys used?

Comment: Given solution is working fine, for me when I download app from play store and try login then it gives me different hash than generated from release keystore.

Comment: take care with uppercase letters

Comment: Just shame on Facebook because of POOR document

Comment: you don't need to remove the debug hash key, just keep it and add the new one, worked for me

Answer (score 43):

This is a case that could have possibly occurred and what solved my error:

In the https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts after you run

**OSX/Linux:**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

**Windows:**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

When `Enter keystore password:` is asked **you may have accidentally typed a wrong password**, the default password is "[android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18590149/8407719)". Typing any other password will give you a different/wrong hash key. Paste the correct hash key in the `Key Hashes` field on your [app page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)

This solved my problem, hope this helps whoever made this particular error that I made

Comment: Is it possible to change the default password? if so how\where?

Comment: @Coder123 just create your own `debugAlt.jks` in another directory with different password and key and put it in your `signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file(new File('../debugKey.jks'))
            storePassword "Qwerty123"
            keyAlias "debug"
            keyPassword "Qwerty123"
        }
}`

Comment: you mean we should compulsorily use "android" as password? where is it written?

Comment: @user1090751 click on the "android" link in my answer for more details. You can create your own password as pointed out in the previous comment

Comment: Thank you for this password! That solved it for me!

Answer (score 40):

I faced the same issue while development and needed to get the hash key to test sharing on facebook, and while solving this I went through couple of issues

1- the command facebook provide to get the hash key by using openSSL command didn't give me the right hash that I got by extracting the signature from Package info with code.
getting the hash by the second way was correct.

2- For some reason, In the documentation they tell you to go to developer settings and add the hash key for 'Sample App' there, I thought every hashkey for a developer should be there, and that was my mistake, every app has it's own hash keys field to add to, go to your app/settings/android.

[image]

well that was it.. and for the records I used openssl-0.9.8k_X64 on a Windows 7 x64 bit
and it just generates a wrong hash I don't know why

I used this code to get the hash:

```
private void printKeyHash() {
    // Add code to print out the key hash
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("YOUR PACKAGE NAME", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("KeyHash:", e.toString());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e("KeyHash:", e.toString());
    }
}
```

but be careful that this may not also print in logs the correct keyhash, at least on my device and machine, when I debug it, in a watch it shows the correct hash just before printing the logs, but in logs it shows another hash and the first one was the correct one.

anyway you can also use a command or eclipse to view the SHA hexadecimal sequence for your key and convert it to base 64 online, there are websites that may help
http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en

Good luck

Comment: this one did it for me! thanks buddy! i added that code into my oncreate function for my mainactivity and check the result in my logcat console, filtered by "KeyHash" and got that key pasted in my app dashboard, it worked perfectly !

Comment: i sent my app to a friend, and he has the same issue... it's wokring for me but he can't log ! why is that?

Comment: Thanks! It was the only answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 37):

I encountered a similar problem.  The solution is surprisingly simple.

The error message looks like this:

```
07-05 ...... Invalid key hash. The key hash sL1***************VY= does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/150*******778
07-05 ......     at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:191)
```

Simply log into https://developers.facebook.com , select the "Settings" tab, and add the key hash "sL1***************VY=" to the list of saved Key hashes in the Android panel.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Its a perfect answer

Comment: and, when asked for debug key password, which you never set, type `android` and thank me later :)

Comment: exception doesn't return the key hash anymore

Comment: even this didn't work for me, I uninstalled facebook app and it worked as mentioned in another answer

Answer (score 22):

---2019----- This is how i solved this problem

1. in android studio in right panel
   `Gradle>App>android>signingReport` copy **SHA1**
2. and open http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php to convert
   your SHA1 value to base64.

This is what Facebook requires
get the generated hash " ********************= " and copy the key hash to the facebook app.

Comment: Thanks, This solved my problem. Why keytool version not working it is interesting

Answer (score 17):

Adding SHA1 keys from Eclipse/keytool helped me only when creating the app on FB, then after rebuilding I would always get the OP error.

What solved my issue was adding the key in the error message to the Facebook dashboard settings.

Comment: For debug key alright, but how can I know about error message from app installed via apk?

Answer (score 13):

Follow these steps in order to generate the correct key hashes.

1. Open your project in android studio and run the project.
2. Click on Gradle menu.
3. Select your app and expand task tree.
4. Double click on android -> signingReport and see the magic
   [image: Sample Image]
5. Result after clicking above tab
   [image: Result after clicking above tab]
6. Copy the SHA1 key and browse [SHA1 key to key hash](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php)
7. After converting the SHA1 key to key hash copy the new key hash and paste it in facebook console. This will work like charm.

Comment: Nice easy solution, just make sure you copy the sha1 from the correct Variant, in my case it was release.

Answer (score 13):

**Edited: 2023 Solution**

This worked for me

1. Go to Google Play Console
2. Select Release Management
3. Choose App Signing
4. Convert App-Signing Certificate SHA-1 to Base64 (this will be different than your current upload certificate) using this tool: http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en
5. Enter Base64 converted SHA-1 into your Facebook Developer dashboard settings and try again.

[image: your Google Play SHA-1]

Comment: Sir you saved my day. How come that a single crucial details like this is not mentioned in documentation? Unbelievable.

Comment: finally. working properly with this solution after day by day stuck. The solution can also be used if you can log in using a browser but cannot do so when using the installed Facebook app

Answer (score 12):

1. Check your Key hash value.
2. Uninstall the Facebook application from your phone.
3. Then try again using SDK.

This solved my problem.

Comment: Uninstalling FB app solved the problem!! Thank you :)

Comment: @Rezaul Karim  it works, but what if i want to make it work without installing fb app?

Comment: Just clearing storage on the facebook app worked for me.

Comment: this old answer work out. I tried all did not work. yes uninstall Facebook app it will show in browser then it work.

Comment: I uninstalled the Facebook app, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

**While generating release Hash key, Note this**

**For Windows**

When generating the hash key for production you need to use openssl-0.9.8e_X64.zip on windows, you cannot use openssl-0.9.8k_X64.zip

The versions produce different hash keys, for some reason 9.8k does not work correctly... 9.8e does.

OR

Use this below flow

This is how i solved this problem Download your APK to your PC in java jdk\bin folder in my case C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_121\bin go to java jdk\bin folder and run cmd then copy the following command in your cmd

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile yourapkname.apk
```

Copy the SHA1 value to your clip board like this CD:A1:EA:A3:5C:5C:68:FB:FA:0A:6B:E5:5A:72:64:DD:26:8D:44:84 and open http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php to convert your SHA1 value to base64.

**For MAC**

Step 1:

Generate SHA1 key by using below command
keytool -list -v -keystore *Keystore path*
Enter Keystore password.
Copy SHA1 Key.

Step 2:
Open this link - http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php
Paste the SHA1 Key in Hex String
Click convert button
Get the Release Keyhash in Output value

Comment: this solved my problem `keytool -list -printcert -jarfile yourapkname.apk` :)

Answer (score 7):

I have had this Problem for two months now. My key hashes have been pyling up to 9. 
Today i finally found the simple solution:

**STEP 1:**

Install the facebook sdk you downloaded from the facebook developer page on your phone. Don´t install the normal facebook app. Make sure you can log into facebook. Then log out.

**STEP 2:**

Export your app with your final release key as an apk, like you would when uploading it to the playstore.

**STEP 3:**

Put the Apk file on your phone via usb cable or usb stick.

**STEP 4:**

Install your app, using a file manager: For example 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm

**STEP 5:**

Launch your app and try to log in with facebook. 
A dialog will open and tell you: "the key  has not been found in the facebook developer console

**STEP 6:**

Write down the key.

**STEP 7:**

Put it into your facebook developer console and save. 
Now you are done.
Anyone that downloads your app, published with earlier used keystore can log into facebook.

Enjoy

Comment: am fallowing your tips pasted that facebook-universalsignin.apk in to mobile and istalled that.and then my app install and runned in that situation also facebook popup openned for login no other dialog box coming please help me

Comment: Did you install the facebook sdk form the developer page and uninstall the normal facebook app from the playstore?

Answer (score 6):

It is looks crazy but it work

Really issue because of you privite facebook account got this app and hash key of this account does't comparable

But you musn't to faced this error with real user. But I am not sure

Eventually follow next step :

1. Go to your private facebook account which you try to log in
2. Then click More in app dir

[image]

3. Click Settings

[image]

And then click cross

[image]

And now you can login with facebook. But next time if you log out and than will try log in again you faced with the same issue...

It is also weird...

But I don't bellieve that facebook don't know about this ...

Comment: Did you find any solution around this?

Answer (score 6):

I am also getting the same issue when user try to Login with Facebook.

> Not Working: Facebook App is Installed in Device.
>
> Working: Facebook app is not installed

So,  following Code is resolved the issue event the Facebook app is installed in device.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY); //This Line Solved Issue
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(context, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
```

Answer (score 4):

What I found was that my SHA-1 that was used to sign the app to be uploaded to the Google Playstore was not correct. I realized that my app was being signed by the Google Play Store with a different token. I followed these steps:

1. Go to Google Play Console
2. Click Release Management
3. Click App Signing
4. Convert App-Signing Certificate SHA-1 to Base64 (this will be different than your current upload certificate)
5. Enter Base64 converted SHA-1 into my Facebook Developer dashboard
   settings

   I am now able to log into my app when the Facebook is downloaded on and Android device.

Answer (score 4):

**For Windows Only:**

At first I used "openssl-0.9.8k_X64.zip" for generate hash of key. This problem appears.

Then I used the openssl version "**openssl-0.9.8e_X64.zip**" in windows. Then the problem solved.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads

I think most of us having same problem.

Comment: How did you know this. Thanks it solved my issue.

Comment: This is what worked for me in 2022, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Using Debug key store including android's debug.keystore present in .android folder was generating a strange problem; the log-in using facebook login button on android app would happen perfectly as desired for the first time. But when ever I Logged out and tried logging in, it would throw up an error saying: This app has no android key hashes configured. Please go to http:// ....

Creating a Keystore using keytool command(keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA1withRSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000) and putting this keystore in my projects topmost parent folder and making a following entry in projects build.gradle file solved the issue:

```
 signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("my-release-key.keystore")
            storePassword "passpass"
            keyAlias "alias_name"
            keyPassword "passpass"
        }    }
```

Please note that you always use the following method inside onCreate() of your android activity to get the key hash value(to register in developer.facebook.com site of your app) instead of using command line to generate hash value as command line in some cased may out put a wrong key hash:

```
    public  void showHashKey(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.superreceptionist",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());

                 String sign=Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                Log.e("KeyHash:", sign);
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sign,     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            Log.d("KeyHash:", "****------------***");
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: showHashKey function works like a charm getting the key, tnx

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem. I found that I used wrong hashkey. keytool printed wrong hashkey because I run command with wrong alias.
Please check your command again.It will resolve your issue

```
keytool -exportcert -alias "test fb sdk" -storepass android -keypass android -keystore "C:\keystore.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Answer (score 3):

For signing the developer build, you will use the keystore and key generated by Android Studio. You can retrieve this with the following command:

`keytool -exportcert -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The password was the thing.

Answer (score 3):

Connect your real device and Just run command `adb logcat | grep hash` and look for something like `Key hash ABCDEFGH1234= does not match any stored key`. Now save this hash on your fb developer console.

Answer (score 2):

**On Debug**

Copy Paste This code inside OnCreate method

```
       try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    getApplication().getPackageName(),
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("KeyHash e1",e.getLocalizedMessage() +"");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.d("KeyHash e2", e.getLocalizedMessage() +"");
        }
```

Open **Logcat** and Filter/find 'D/KeyHash:'

```
D/KeyHash: D5uFR+65hafzotdih/dOfp14FpE=
```

Then Open **https://developers.facebook.com/** and Open YourApp/Setting/Basic
Scroll down to **Android Section** Then Paste the Key Hashes and Save

Answer (score 2):

**MAY 2023 SOLUTION**
[image]

1. Android studio -> Gradle -> Top left icon -> write 'gradle signingReport' -> Enter
2. Copy SHA1 key
3. Open http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php -> paste key into 'Hex string:' -> Convert -> Copy base 64
4. Open https://developers.facebook.com/ -> My Apps -> Select your app -> Settings -> Basic -> Scroll down -> Add copied base64 to 'Key hashes list' -> Save changes

You're welcome

Answer (score 1):

I got simular problem. After signing and publishing my app to the google PlayStore it seems the Hash has changed. 
I added the new Hash (as mentioned) in the Facebook messaged to the Key Hashes in my app on developers.facebook.com/app//settings. Now it works again.

Answer (score 1):

You are may be using wrong password the default password for debug keystore is android.

Answer (score 1):

My problem is possibly due to the hash got wrongly generated by the openssl itself, if anyone is facing similar problem using the method provided by the facebook android guide itself.

One way to deal with this is :

1. Get your sha1 using this tool :

`keytool -exportcert -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v`

2. convert it to base64 using this tool

http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php

credit :

https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/424#issuecomment-469047955

Comment: yes, same for me. i did it right but openssl did something and it was not correct. It took 6hours of my time.

Answer (score 0):

@Ketan Ramani answer helped me but in my case, I was not using the LoginManager instead I was registering a callback on an image if you are using **registerCallback** on any image by making it a login button use below code

```
 loginButton.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried everything on this page but no success, until i took a break, then when I continue working on this, without changing anything, it suddenly works. Maybe (just maybe) facebook **needs times** to register the key

Answer (score 0):

In the right side of Android Studio go to `Gradle -> Tasks -> android -> signingReport` and run it.
Copy the SHA-1 key and transform it into base64 using [this](https://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php), and then add the converted base64 hash to your app in the Facebook Developer Console.
If you want to use a release hash run this in the command line:`keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_KEYSTORE_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_KEYSTORE | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`
Where `YOUR_KEYSTORE` is the path to the `.keystore` or `.jks` that you used as `signinConfig` for your release variant and `YOUR_KEYSTORE_ALIAS` is the alias which you gave when you created the keystore. If you do not remember the alias you can run `keytool -v -list -keystore YOUR_KEYSTORE` and see all the info about the keystore

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem when I so facebook integration, and I solved this error by this steps:

1. open android folder(File/open/yourFlutterProject/android) in your flutter project
2. now you can see gradle field in right-side top penal
   -------[image: Gragle Image]
3. do this steps(gradle/android/app/tasks/android/signingReport) and click it.
4. now you can see your project SHA-1 key, note it.
5. now open this site([Site Link](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php)) and convert SHA-1 to keyhash and you get your keyhash value, note it.
6. not update/change this keyhash with currunt keyhash in your developer.facebook console
7. now its run perfect.

Answer (score 0):

What worked in my case:

- I took the key from Firebase
- went to http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en
- used that code in the facebook developer console

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to get your APK file,
Use the keytool to get your app's signature as follows:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin> ./keytool -list -printcert -jarfile myapp.coolapp.apk
```

In my case, my apk was placed in the same directory as the keytool, I later deleted it.
After running the above command, you have a list of keys, copy the SHA1 key
Convert it to base64 using [this tool](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php)
Copy the Base64 conversion,
Go to facebook dev portal, navigate to your app, then "settings/basic"
Then go to the key hashes section.
Paste the Base64 hash there, and facebook login will work just fine.

[Here is an article that explains](https://medium.com/@junaidahmed/invalid-key-hash-the-key-hash-does-not-match-any-stored-key-hashes-5aeb81539d64) these steps in detail:

Answer (score 0):

For me what eventually worked was to use the debug.keystore that is stored inside the android/app folder. So basically running the keytool command from the app folder like that:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore android/app/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

The password is: android

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue. Then I uninstalled my **Facebook App**. Then it is opening with my default browser. Then the login/signup was succeeded via facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the hash and add it to the facebook console worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**I faced same issue**
If your login is working without installing facebook app and not working when facebook app is installed due to error "hash key has not match" then do following steps

1 ) Launch your app and try to log in with facebook. A dialog will open and tell you: "the key has not been found in the facebook developer console and also show the hash key.

2 ) Note down that hash key.

3 ) Put it into your facebook developer console where you first generated your api key and remove the hash key with new and save. Now you are done. Anyone that downloads your app, published with earlier used keystore can log into facebook.

Answer (score -3):

Check your google-services.json . May be it is different one. Download your latest google-services.json and then run the app. Hope it helps.