# Android app fails to run on a device

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am trying to build an android app with **Facebook login**. The app runs successfully on the emulator. But every time I install and run the app on an Android device and tries to login I get the error as in the following screenshot:[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20301025/235710

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Facebook application should have key hashes that are valid to the keystore you are using the following code:

```
  try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.yourpackage.name",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

or follow this link instructions [Facebook Android Generate Key Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash)

**Then add this generated key hash to the keyhashes in android settings in your Facebook application**