# facebook integration in android error

Tags: android, facebook

everyone

I am working on android application where i need  to post something on facebook from my application.

Here for this purpose i have followed [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) tutorial.

Here when i run my application by putting new appID its run fine first time , but after doing some modification ( or not) in my application when i run my application again ( using same appID) its show me this error.

**This app has no Android Key hashes configured.Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/myAppID**.

Can some one please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Delete your application on developers.facebook.com
2. Delete the file debug.keystore (located under
   C:\Users\yourUserName.android)
3. Generate a new key (by running your app again)
4. Create a new app on developers.facebook.com and add the new hash key
5. Then re-run your app

Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301025/facebook-key-hash-does-not-match-any-stored-key-hashes)