# Android key hash blocked by Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-authentication, android-keystore

I came across very strange issue with the Facebook Key Hashes. The Facebook SDK is used in my Android App to provide the native authentication. Everything worked just fine, until today morning when made some temporary configuration changes. I removed the original Key Hash (*keyhash1*) and replace it with another one (*keyhash2*). After some testing, restored the configuration, but my original Key Hash *keyhash1* stopped to work... The message says "*keyhash1* does not match any stored key hashes".

I double checked everything, tried to rebuild the app many times, but this didn't succeed. After few hours of digging, found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20304015) answer. Since I can't delete this app (it is already used by many users), I decided to try reproduce this issue somewhere else. Prepared test app, added and removed the Key Hash few times and voila, issue successfully reproduced.
Based on mentioned stackoverflow answer, removed the Facebook App, and created a new one using the same Key Hash, it started to work again.

The question how can I fix the original application? Is that normal that Facebook blocked the Key Hashes?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to work!

Here is how I fixed it, if somone have similar issue:

My Key Hash has stopped working, when I removed all the other Key Hashes and leave only this one. I was trying to add it and remove many times but it didn't help...

Eventually I did the following hook - removed all the Key Hashes, add a new one (fake, different than the production one) and then (on the second place) added the one that was initially blocked. Since then, everything started to work again! After that, was able to removed the fake Key Hash and leave only the production one.

You may also look into reported facebook bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/841773542574041

Answer (score -1):

@tludek,you don't need hash key for facebook,follow this tutorial  [links here](https://github.com/slidenerd/FaceBookv4.0HelloWorld)

Comment: One of the first sentence in your tutorial is "To generate hash key..."