# Facebook key hash does not match any stored key hashes on second run

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-apps

I am trying to use facebook api for login on my android application. After following the tutorials I was able to get the confirmation screen after clicking login by facebook button. But when i run my application second time I get "Facebook key hash does not match any stored key hashes" error.

I follow other posts on stackoverflow, deleted my application and created once again etc. but on second run I again get the same error.

[Facebook key hash does not match any stored key hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301025/facebook-key-hash-does-not-match-any-stored-key-hashes)

Do you know what can be wrong and why I do not get on first run but I get this error on second run?

Comment: generating key for debug? or release?

Comment: generated debug key.

Comment: how  are u getting the hash key?

Comment: I am using command which is shown on facebook developer pages.

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
 public void Get_hash_key() {
        PackageInfo info;
        try {
            info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your_package_name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md;
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
                Log.e("hash key", something);
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
            Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("exception", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

add your package name and call this function in `onCreate`() of your Mainactivity

it will print the Hash key on logcat...

copy and paste the key on developer panel ,remove other keys

Comment: I tried this but on second run again it fails, because on second run it  creates different hash code. I think that is the problem. As I understand after every run the code changes but on the server there is only code which I registered and therefore it does not match. So why my hash code changes always?

Answer (score 0):

Create a valid keystore to your android app:

(Windows)

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore fisherbook.keystore -alias fisherbook -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Generate facebook hash key:

(Windows)

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <KEYSTORE_ALIAS> -keystore <COMPLETE_KEYSTORE_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Or look at facebook error: "Invalid key hash. The key  does not match any store hashes..."
There is your facebook hash key!

Then put your hash at app/settings (android) at facebook developer website.