# Invalid Key Hash Error When Run using Real Device

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am using **react-native-fbsdk** on my project. When I ran the application using Android Emulator it works just fine but error occured when I ran it using real device.

> Invalid key hash. The key hash xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/

Tested on Nexus 5x (Android 7.1.2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook key hash does not match any stored key hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301025/facebook-key-hash-does-not-match-any-stored-key-hashes)