# Facebook key hash error

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-apps, android-facebook

And again. I've got Facebook key hash error [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58q3v.png). Carefully noted down that hash key and then insert it into "Key hashes" field into my Facebook app. But this doesn't helps to me, the same error is shown again when I'd try to sign in.

Note that the first sign in (just after app has been installed) completes succesfully. Also the same story with Debug key hash work good. Any suggestions?

Could it be depends of [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook key hash does not match any stored key hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301025/facebook-key-hash-does-not-match-any-stored-key-hashes)

Comment: @Zoe Best comment under approved answer: Now what do we do if we already have thousands of users, just recreating the app isn't exactly a great idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create new app using new app id in Google Play console, and not using Google Play App Signing. As a result I've got new key hash (hash of my sign key), and Facebook app took it normally.