# Firebase Facebook Login Hash Keys Issue

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Login method for FireBase on my Android App. The error is the following: "Key hash B5dWUEYfZJL/...........jyA= does not match any stored key hashes". The error occurs when I have already installed the app, delete it and do a reinstall. The similar problem is described in the following link..

[Facebook key hash does not match any stored key hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301025/facebook-key-hash-does-not-match-any-stored-key-hashes)

The suggested solution is to go to your Facebook Profile, delete the app from the permissions list in "Settings".like this..

[image]

The solution provided works and solves the problem, but you cannot go and ask a user of the app to go to his/her settings and delete app permissions when this happens.. Is there a way to avoid this problem in programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I used to do when this happened was to add the key shown in the error message in the facebook console, but then I found that anoying and I discovered that I was using debug keys, which usually change.

Now I apply this method: Right before I generate the apk I run the release version of my app in the emulator, but I activate this method in my splash screen:

```
public void discoveryKeyHarsh() {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.hmr.android.taskr",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
    }
```

It will show a keyhash that I then add to my facebook console. And I never had the "key does not match any stored key hashes" again.