# login facebook react native using react-native-fbsdk

Tags: react-native

There is no Facebook app installed, the login works.
But if the Facebook app is installed, despite I added the key hash app, Facebook developers, getting this error:

```
Error: SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1349195 [message]: The key hash does not match any stored key hashes.
```

Answer (score 0):

please follow this instructions

`Add your development and release key hashes`

To generate a development key hash, on Mac, run the following command:

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

On Windows, run this command:

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

and you have option ,to add multiple Key Hashes... add multiple generated key hashs.

Comment: Login fail with error: Error: SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1349195 [message]: The key hash does not match any stored key hashes.

Comment: Try this ``https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301025/facebook-key-hash-does-not-match-any-stored-key-hashes``