# keystore file missing in titanium

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have published one android app on Feb 4,2015 which was developed in `TITANIUM`...app was directly published from the location where it was generated and i remember it dint ask about any keystore file or any release version apk.

Now I have redeveloped the same app on `PHONEGAP` and titanium is now shifted to appcelerator so i can't run that app on titanium platform and the problem is i am not getting that keystore file.

I have to keep its bundle id same as previous version so that existing users get proper update but for that I require the same keystore file.

Can anyone help on this issue?

If you require any other information then let me know.

Comment: See [this response](https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/123704/what-keystore-does-titanium-studio-use-to-build-android-app-during-development) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589694/i-have-never-set-any-passwords-to-my-keystore-and-alias-so-how-are-they-created). Usually by default, the debug keystore is stored at $HOME/.android/debug.keystore when developing on Android studio.  Hope it helps. Also i would advise you to sign your apps with your own release key.

Comment: correct solution. :-)

Comment: posting the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [response](https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/123704/what-keystore-does-titanium-studio-use-to-build-android-app-during-development) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589694/i-have-never-set-any-passwords-to-my-keystore-and-alias-so-how-are-they-created). Usually by default, the debug keystore is stored at $HOME/.android/debug.keystore when developing on Android studio. Hope it helps. Also i would advise you to sign your apps with your own release key.